# MIMIC-III: Negative cultures and microbiologyevents

Tags: mimic-iii

In MIMIC-III, where do negative cultures appear? Is this different between CareVue patients and Metavision patients?

Despite the documentation's assertion ([here](https://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/microbiologyevents/)) that "If the specimen is null, then the culture had no growth reported.", there are very few cases where either the spec_itemid or org_itemid are empty in the microbiologyevents table(I think it's less than 2k out of 328k).  Also, in a manual inspection, it looks like most rows have an antibiotic test done, so as to determine sensitivity of the culture.

PROCEDUREEVENTS_MV seems to have information on cultures for Metavision patients, but this whole table confuses me too.

Edit: Clarified that paragraph 2 refers to the microbiologyevents table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative cultures were added to the `microbiologyevents` table in version 1.4 of MIMIC-III: http://mimic.physionet.org/about/releasenotes/

> - #188 - Negative microbiology cultures are now recorded in MICROBIOLOGYEVENTS - negative cultures can be identified by a NULL value for the organism name (ORG_NAME).

Negative cultures were not available in prior versions of MIMIC-III.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!  Any comment on the Procedureevents_mv table? It has a number of culture events listed for a variety of tissues (e.g., itemid 225401). Are these also limited to only those cultures which result in a positive result as well?  What is the meaning of the procedureevents_mv table in general?

Comment: That table is sourced from the patient flowsheet. It's just a way of charting data with a start time and an end time. Usually they are procedures since those fit nicely into this framework. I don't think they are 100% compliant on it though, so if something isn't charted, it may still have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears, an entry in the microbiologyevents table means that the test was performed, and a NULL value indicates that no microbiological agent was detected, for that particular agent in that particular specimen at that particular date/time stamp.